# Can we import PGP encryption key in Google could KMS and use that key decrypt the files in google storage?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-kms

Can we import PGP encryption key in Google could KMS and use that key decrypt the files in google storage ?

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation, you can find the [list of supported key type](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/key-import#supported_key_formats). PGP private keys aren't supported. You can store it in secret manager (and, behind the scene, KMS will be used to encrypt your secret).

Or you can encrypt it manually. Generate an encryption key with Cloud KMS, encrypt the PGP private key, and store the encryption somewhere (in your app, in GCS, in Git repo,...). The only thing that you have to do when you want to use it is to perform the opposite process and decipher the PGP private key with Cloud KMS.